# pass objective c object and primitive type into a void *

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to pass 2 variables:

```
UIImage * img
int i
```

into another method that only takes a (void *)

I tried making a C struct containing both img and i

```
struct MyStruct {
    UIImage *img;
    int i;
}
```

but xcode gives me an error saying "ARC forbids Objective-C objects in structs or unions"

The next thing I tried is to write an objective-c class MyStruct2 containing img and i, alloc-initing an instance of it and typecasting it as (__bridge void*) before passing it to the method. Seems little involved for my use case. Seems like there should be a better way.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Thank you.

Edit based on comments: I have to use void * as it is required by the UIView API. I created a selector as mentioned by UIVIew API

```
+ (void)setAnimationDidStopSelector:(SEL)selector
```

Please see documentation for setAnimationDidStopSelector at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html . It says ... The selector should be of the form:

```
    - (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

I want to pass both img and i into the (void *)context argument.

Comment: Why not change the method you are passing them to?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not changing the method itself?

Comment: @Anne maybe he's using pthreads and the callback can take 1 param only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARC cannot follow ObjC objects in plain old C structs. It tracks pointers on the stack, or in ObjC and C++ objects, which are copied using methods, explicit or implicit, but under the compiler control anyway.

So... use a class. C++ if you like it, or :

```
@interface MyNotSoPlainStruct

@property ( nonatomic, strong ) UImage* image;
@property ( nonatomic ) int i;

@end

@implementation MyNotSoPlainStruct
@end

MyNotSoPlainStruct* foo = [MyNotSoPlainStruct new];
foo.image = …
foo.i = …
```

and there you go.

The solution needs more lines, that's true, but you have a much better control on how things are done, including the image life cycle. You can use a strong pointer, or a weak one if it suits your needs better.

Of course, you can also use either a dictionary or an array. Literals make that especially easy:

```
NSDictionary* arguments = @{ @"image" : <image>, @"i" : @( <int> ) };
arguments[@"i"].intValue returns the int you need.
```

Pretty easy.

**edit**

Forgot the transfer part, oops :). So then:

You must use the following annotations:

```
void* argumentsPointer = (__bridge_retained void*) arguments;
```

arguments is retained, and that reference is no longer managed by ARC.

When you receiver your pointer back, you must convert it:

```
NSDictionary* arguments = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*) argumentsPointer;
```

Using __bridge only may result in a dangling pointer if the last known reference disappear. If you want that void* to retain the dictionary, you must use __bridge_retained first, then __bridge_transfer.

Comment: Thanks fabric. If I use NSDictionary, I would need to typecast it to (__bridge void*) before passing it to the method. Right?

Comment: added the transfer thingy to the answer :)

Comment: Clever use of `__bridge_retained` AND `__bridge_transfer` on pointers. Never thought of that!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    __unsafe_unretained UIImage *img;
    int i;
}
```

However, if you do this, you must keep in mind that the `img` field will not automatically retain and release its `UIImage`.

If you post more details about your “method that only takes a (void *)”, we might be able to give you better advice.

### EDIT

You have updated your question to say that you need to pass a `void *` to the `animationDidStop:finished:context:` selector.  Since you're using ARC, I know you're targetting iOS 4.0 or later, so you should just use  `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` instead.  Then you don't need to pass a `void *`.

```
UIImage *img = someImage();
int i = someInt();

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
    // set the animatable properties here
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    doSomethingWithImageAndInteger(img, i);
}];
```

Comment: Rob, I like part 1 of your answer. *Really* simple.

Comment: Be careful with it tho, you're opening a bag of hurts playing with __unsafe_unretained. Notice the "unsafe" word, here for a reason. __unretained would have sufficed. :)